# Laravel: how to validate that required subarray items are present?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.7

In my laravel POST endpoint, Im expecting an "items" parameter in the following form:

```
$items => [
  ['item' => 'a', 'item_slot' => 1],
  ['item' => 'b', 'item_slot' => 2],
  ['item' => 'c', 'item_slot' => 3],
]
```

I want to validate that all the required item slots were provided.

I have an array of required slots `$requiredItemSlots = [1, 2]`

What validation rules should I use to make sure that item slots in `$requiredItemSlots` were present? Note, i don't want to limit the provided slots to the required ones, i just need to make sure that the required slots were filled.

For now I have something like:

```
'items.*.item' => 'required',
'items.*.item_slot' => 'required|distinct'
```

To ensure that no duplicate slots were passed in.

Originally I tried doing

```
'items.*.item_slot' => Rule::in($requiredItemSlots)
```

But that's not correct because not all the slots are necessarily required.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to make a [custom rule](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/validation#custom-validation-rules), something like that:

```
'items' => [
    'required', 
    'array', 
    function ($attribute, $value, $fail) {
        $required = [1, 2];
        // Cast to collection for easier checks
        $items = collect($value);
        foreach ($required as $r) {
            if (! $items->firstWhere('item_slot', '=', $r)) {
                $fail("$r has to be present in items.");
            }
        }
    },
], // ..other validation rules
```

Comment: `function ($attribute, $value, $fail) use ($requiredSlots) {...` will allow you to access your $requiredSlots from within the Closure without having to define it within, if that is useful.

Answer (score 0):

You may use a combination of `distinct`, `in:1,2,3` and `size:3` to validate the input:

```
'items' => 'required|array|size:3',
'items.*.item_slot' => [
    'required',
    'distinct',
    Rule::in($requiredSlots),
]
```

With `size:3` you force the array to have exactly `3` elements. With `distinct` you make sure there are no duplicates in the `item_slot` element field. And with `Rule::in($requiredSlots)` you ensure that there are no unknown `item_slots` given.